# Second page does not work with Codes in the first page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main page that I have loaded another page on it via ajax when document is ready ,also I have a button that when I click  It I shows an alert and, I have that button in the second page too. but when i click on it in that page that code does not work ?
how can i solve this problem ?

because I do not want to repeat `js codes` on the second page ?

here is my first page code :

**first page code:**

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="captcha" style="border:1px solid red;">
</div>
<div class="details1">cccc</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(".captcha").load("/secondpage.htm");
$(".details1").click( function()
{
 alert('button clicked');
}
);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my second page that I have loaded into div with classname captcha:

**second page code:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <section class="details1"> Details </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is `filter.inc` loaded ?

Comment: @AndreiTodorut yes it is second page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to create new elements on-the-fly, you can not use standard click etc. events. Dynamically created elements are not born with the same event handlers as the existing elements. You have to dynamically attach event handlers to newly created elements.

Replace 'click' with 'on'.

```
 $("body").on("click", ".details1", function(){
 alert('button clicked');
});
```

Comment: @Newman, This answer can be much more useful if you can add an explanation to it.